# How to integrate pry with RubyMine IRB console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine, pry

How to use pry to debug rails app instead of RubyMine IRB console?
Shall I just add pry-rails and pry to my gemfile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported yet, [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9302).

Comment: Thanks, I hope community who see this question will go ahead and vote too :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported - starting with RubyMine 2020.3.0.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/running-console.html